# How to set gcc -E depth (preprocessing level)?

Tags: c, gcc, c-preprocessor

Say we have main.c:

```
#define f() { \
    foo();    \
    bar();    \
}

#define F() { \
    f();      \
    f();      \
}

F();
```

Now if we `gcc -E main.c -o main.i`, in main.i there is:

```
# 1 "main.c"
# 1 "<built-in>"
# 1 "<command-line>"
# 1 "main.c"
# 11 "main.c"
{ { foo(); bar(); }; { foo(); bar(); }; };
```

What if I don't want inner macros (like `f()`) to be expanded. How can I get something like:

```
# 1 "main.c"
# 1 "<built-in>"
# 1 "<command-line>"
# 1 "main.c"
# 11 "main.c"
{ f(); f(); };
```

Also if it's possible then how can I tune expansion depth?

Comment: Maybe a possible workaround, only if you are allowed to change the source code (and even in this case, it would still be difficult to apply in large projects), would be to inject the proper `#undef f` in the suitable locations, possibly in some `#ifdef`-`#endif` block to easily activate/disactivate through the command line (via `-D`). This still wouldn't work in all cases, though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple answer (at least for the C preprocessors I know):

You cannot - Not in the general case. Macros are expanded by recursion and the recursion depth cannot be set with, for example, GNU `cpp`.

In specific cases where the "outer" and the "inner" macro are defined in different files you might be able to *somewhat* achieve what you want by simply not including (or providing an empty include of) the file that defines the "outer" definition and feeding the file with the "inner" definition directly into cpp.

I do, however, have a cpp implementation for an embedded system that actually *does print* every recursion step to stderr when executed with the highest verbosity ("-vvv"), although that doesn't help you with gcc/cpp - But this at least shows that something like you want is technically possible.